# Sublime Text wrap selection with snippet

Tags: css, less, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've been digging into Sublime's snippets, plugins and macros, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to turn this:

```
.content {
    color: @blue;
}
```

Into this:

```
.content {
    color: darken(@blue, 5%);
}
```

Ideally, I'd be able to select the `@blue` part, hit a command, and wrap the whole thing properly.

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Comment: Sure, you can play all sorts of games with selected text--what have you tried?

Comment: Not replace, exactly. I want it the darken, 5% part to wrap the @blue part and add parenthesis.

Comment: I can't figure out the key binding part. I can get a snippet to work with a tab trigger, but hitting tab will delete what's in my selection! Hence, it needs to be a key binding. I think.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html):

Tools -> New Snippet... -> save as `darken.sublime-snippet` in `Data\Packages\User\`

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[darken($SELECTION, 5%);]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>darken</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Scope the tab trigger will be active in -->
    <scope>source.css</scope>
    <!-- Optional: Description to show in the menu -->
    <description>Darken Snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

And keybind:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+o"], 
  "command": "insert_snippet", 
  "args": { "name": "Packages/User/darken.sublime-snippet" } },
```

**EDIT:**
It would be even better if you add `$1` right after the `$SELECTION`, then the cursor will jump to the selected word or right in the place where it has to be written if it's not selected.

Change the above snippet's second line to this:

```
<content><![CDATA[darken($SELECTION$1, 5%);]]></content>
```

Comment: Right. I noticed that and thought the same yesterday.  Thanks again, Vlakarados. Very helpful.

Comment: I could see that you might want to wrap a selection in an arbitrary tag, that makes sense to me. But did you really want something this specific? It seems like a lot of effort for this use case.

Comment: Better yet: `${1:$SELECTION}` selects the selection.

Comment: Nice but for me it does not work with a tabTrigger set. Selecting something and typing "tab" will always replace the selection with a tab instead of triggering the snippet. Its correctly triggered if nothing is selected (on Mac, Sublime 3).

Comment: You can use the tabTrigger for the empty snippet, and the keybinding to wrap a selection. Alternately, if you don't want to use a keybinding, you can also search through all your snippets with `cmd+shift+P`.